# Create output file based on changing input value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following txt files (10000s) in multiple directories eg.

```
BaseDirectory\04_April\2019-04-14\UniqeDirectoryName1 (username)\345308457384745637.txt
BaseDirectory\04_April\2019-04-14\UniqeDirectoryName2 (username)\657453456456546543.txt
BaseDirectory\04_April\2019-04-14\UniqeDirectoryName3 (username)\234545743564356774.txt

BaseDirectory\05_May\2019-05-14\UniqeDirectoryName1 (username)\266434564564563565.txt
BaseDirectory\05_May\2019-05-14\UniqeDirectoryName2 (username)\934573845739632048.txt
BaseDirectory\05_May\2019-05-14\UniqeDirectoryName3 (username)\634534534535654501.txt
```

so in other words in each date folder there are multiple directories that again contains text files.

```
import os
import re
import csv

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk("E:\\BaseDir\\"):
    for name in files:
        file_fullinfo = os.path.join(path, name)
        path, filename = os.path.split(file_fullinfo)

        NoExtension = os.path.splitext(file_fullinfo)[0]
        file_noext = str(NoExtension)

        file_splitinfo = re.split('\\\\', file_noext, 0)

        file_month = file_splitinfo[2]
        file_date = file_splitinfo[3]
        file_folder = re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', file_splitinfo[4])
        file_name = file_splitinfo[5]
        file_category = file_folder
```

My script generates the following..

```
['E:', 'BaseDirectory', '04_April', '2019-04-09', 'UniqeDirectoryName', '345308457384745637.txt', 'UniqeDirectoryName']
```

So far so good, writing this to a generic CSV file is also straight forward, but I want to create a new CSV file based on the changing date like this.

```
E:\BaseDir\2019-04-09.csv
file_folder, file_name, file_category
'UniqeDirectoryName', '543968732948754398','UniqeDirectoryName'
'UniqeDirectoryName', '345308457384745637','UniqeDirectoryName'
'UniqeDirectoryName', '324089734983987439','UniqeDirectoryName'

E:\BaseDir\2019-05-14.csv
file_folder, file_name, file_category
'UniqeDirectoryName', '543968732948754398','UniqeDirectoryName'
'UniqeDirectoryName', '345308457384745637','UniqeDirectoryName'
'UniqeDirectoryName', '324089734983987439','UniqeDirectoryName'
```

How can I accomplise this can't quite wrap my head a around it, the struggle of being a Python noob is real.. :)

Comment: So what you're trying to achieve is grouping all the texts files and their contents by unique date?

Comment: Not the content of the file just the file name

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without the first line as a header row it can be achieved quite simply.

```py
output_file_path = 'D:/output_files/' + file_date + '.csv'
with open(file=output_file_path, mode='a') as csv_file: #open a csv file to write to in append mode
csv_file.write("my data\n")
```

if you absolutely must have the header then you can test if the file exists first, if it doesn't exist write the header row

```py
import os.path

output_file_path = 'D:/output_files/' + file_date + '.csv'
if not os.path.exists(output_file_path): #open a csv file to write header row if doesn't exist
    with open(file=output_file_path, mode='a') as csv_file: 
        csv_file.write("my header row\n")

with open(file=output_file_path, mode='a') as csv_file: #open a csv file to write to in append mode
    csv_file.write("my data\n")
```

Comment: Not sure i quite follow you here, file=file_date where do you get this from? when the csv containing the dataset is not open?

Comment: This creates a file called csv_file with the filename as file_date. If that file doesn't exist it will create it for you. If it does exist it will put new data at the end. The next line is where you write what ever data you need to write to the file.

Comment: But this doesn't adjust for the changing dates which are needed for the filename, it just opens a csv file and writes the data...

Comment: It should open a csv_file, or create one if it doesn't exist with the filename of the variable file_date. What you need to do is place that codeblock in your loop that gets the details of the input files, maybe at the bottom. I've edited the answer to make it a little clearer where it's creating the output file.